# serial write to COM port using C/C++ from MATLAB reference code

Tags: c++, c, matlab, serial-port

I am using a simple matlab code to send serial data to a COM port device, however I am having issues and would like an equivalent C/C++ code to achieve the same result. Shown below is the MATLAB code.

```
s_port = serialport('COM1',9600);
configureTerminator(s_port,'CR');

write(s_port,char([50 01]),"char");
pause(1)

write(s_port,char([16 2 150]),"char")

write(s_port,char([55 18]),"char")   
write(s_port,char(54),"char");
```

I attempted to use MATLAB coder, but I don't think there is a stock equivalent to matlab's serialwrite function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the port is named "COM1" and not "/dev/ttyS0" I assume you are running on Windows.

You can `fopen("COM1:")` and `fwrite()` to it, but that won't give you control over baud rate.

For control over serial port settings (baud rate, parity, stop bits, flow control), you need to use the Win32 API (`CreateFile`, build or modify a `DCB structure`, `SetCommState`, `WriteFile`).  [Official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/configuring-a-communications-resource)

On other (POSIX-like) operating systems, you'd use `open`, build or modify a `termios` structure, `tcsetattr`, `write`.  [Examples of termios configuration here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59865656/103167)

There are also some wrapper libraries that abstract away the OS-specific parts, but I can't recommend any of them.